# Strange result file

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a program that read two files ("incompleta.txt" and "completa.txt") and compares if there is same names in both files. Here is how it works:

1. It stores all names from "completa.txt" in an ArrayList;
2. Read "incompleta.txt" file, and compare each line with the ArrayList, if matches, then delete the entry from the ArrayList;
3. Write the ArrayList in a text file ("lista.txt").

The problem is that my "lista.txt" looks like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkwnF.png)

The second line is all confusing and distorted.

My Java Code:

```
private static final List<Character> lista = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("completa.txt"), "UTF-8")) {
        int data = reader.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            char theChar = (char) data;
            data = reader.read();
            lista.add(theChar);
        }

        reader.close();
    }

    try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("incompleta.txt"), "UTF-8")) {
        int data = reader.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            char theChar = (char) data;
            data = reader.read();

            if (lista.contains(theChar)) {
                lista.remove(theChar);
            }
        }

        reader.close();
    }

    try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("lista.txt"), "UTF-8")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            writer.append(lista.get(i));
        }

        writer.close();
    }

    System.out.println("\n[AVISO] LISTA GERADA COM SUCESSO!\n");
}
```

Comment: What is the weird part about that image? The first lines? Where do you get this data?

Comment: What is your input files?

Comment: Oh sorry, here: completa.txt = http://pastebin.com/B1ApuHc1  && incompleta.txt = http://pastebin.com/MLZ3gJe1

Comment: The code is reading and saving characters not lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a list of characters, built from the first file.  Not a list of strings.

Then you go and delete some individual characters, based on the second file.  That leaves some funny-looking words behind; you get letters missing.  Then at the end, you print all of that.  Your output is exactly what I would expect.

Comment: Thanks all you guys, how to solve the problem (my problem, at least):

Just change ArrayList type to String and replace the line char theChar = (char) data; to String myData = Character.toString((char) data);

Answer (score 0):

The autobox feature is not symetric.  Adding 'd' is wrapped in a Character object.
With the remove, there is no autobox. remove('d') is changed to remove(100).
Put an object in the remove(new Character('d'))